# How to process input stream twice in java

Tags: java, io, inputstream, file-handling, outputstream

I have an "InputStream" as input in the public API. I need to read the input stream twice. Is there any way I can read/process inputStream multiple times? If yes, what can be possible caveats?

```
public void doSomething(InputStream inputStream) {

doProcessInputStreamAPI_1 (inputStream)
doProcessInputStreamAPI_2 (inputStream)

}
```

How I can achieve the above flow?
**doProcessInputStreamAPI_1**  and **doProcessInputStreamAPI_2**  are independent and one should not affect other.

Comment: If you're using the same input stream for both, you'll need to reset the input stream when you're ready to read through the stream again.

Comment: @RichardBarker, which requires a buffered stream with a large enough buffer to hold all the stream's contents.

Comment: `InputStream`s do _not_ all support this.

Answer (score 0):

If the input stream handlers are independent, they could be refactored to process the data read from the stream:

```java
public void doSomething(InputStream input) {

    int x;
    while ((x = input.read()) != -1) {
        doProcessInputStreamAPI_1(x);
        doProcessInputStreamAPI_2(x);
    }
}
```